# Python I need to write a loop that creates two seperate running totals, and I don't understand my error

Tags: python, loops

I have a homework problem that I cant figure out, can someone help

--Create a function called sums that will prompt the user to enter integer values (either positive or negative). The function should keep separate running totals of the positive values and the negative values. The user should be allowed to continue entering values until he/she enters a zero to stop.

Here's what I got and it doesn't work

```
  number = int(raw_input("Enter and a positive or negative integer: "))
  def sums(number):
       while (number > 0):
            posnumber = int(raw_input("Enter another number or 0 to quit: "  ))
            number = number + posnumber
            print "The positive total is", number

       while (number < 0):
            negnumber = int(raw_input("Enter another number or 0 to quit: "  ))
            number = number + negnumber
            print "The negative total is", number
```

it just runs the loop under the first iteration, I'm confused as to what to do to correct it

Comment: To the downvoter: It's pretty inappropriate to downvote without some helpful comment.

Answer (score 7):

Because they're separate while loops - the first one is executed, then the second one is executed. You don't want that at all. Here's a layout of what you should do:

> ```
> take a number from input, store it as inputnum
> while inputnum isn't 0
>     determine whether inputnum is positive or negative
>     add inputnum to the either posnumber or negnumber
>     print the total
>     get a new inputnum
> ```

That is, you should have an if inside a while, not two whiles.